# RSelenium: clicking on subsequent links in for loop from a Google search

Tags: r, selenium, dplyr, lapply, rselenium

I'm using `RSelenium` to do some simple Google searches. Setup:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium) # running docker to do this
library(rvest)
library(httr)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L, browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")

books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL teams", key = "enter"))

bookElem <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", "h3.LC20lb")
```

That's the easy part. Now, there are 10 links on that first page, and **I want to click on every link, back out, and then clink the next link.** What's the most efficient way to do that? I've tried the following:

```
bookElem$clickElement()
```

Returns `Error: attempt to apply non-function` - I expected this to click on the first link, but no good. (This works if I take the `s` off of `findElements()` - the above, not the `for` loop below).

```
clack <- lapply(bookElem, function(y) {

   y$clickElement()
   y$goBack() 

})
```

Begets an error, kind of [like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44657998/rselenium-throwing-staleelementreference-error):

```
 Error:      Summary: StaleElementReference
             Detail: An element command failed because the referenced element is no longer attached to the DOM.
             Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Would it be [easier to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531169/rselenium-scraping-links-on-page) `rvest`, within `RSelenium`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could consider grabbing the links and looping through them without going back to the main page.

In order to achieve that, you will have to grab the link elements ("a tag").

```
bookElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")
```

And then extracting the "href" attribute and navigate to that:

```
links <- sapply(bookElems, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})

for(link in links){
  remDr$navigate(link)
  # DO SOMETHING
}
```

Full code would read:

```
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://books.google.com/")
books <- remDr$findElement(using = "css", "[name = 'q']")

books$sendKeysToElement(list("NHL teams", key = "enter"))
bookElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "xpath",
                                "//h3[@class = 'LC20lb']//parent::a")

links <- sapply(bookElems, function(bookElem){
  bookElem$getElementAttribute("href")
})

for(link in links){
  remDr$navigate(link)
  # DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: This worked - and your simple loop is a great base. One can just use `remDr$getCurrentUrl()` to check that it ended on the last link